# How to use custom array in yii2 dataprovider gridView?

Tags: yii2

I have the following array at the top of the view file:

```
$order_status = array(
    'nocourier' => 'در حال جستجوی پیک',
    'accepted' => 'پیک تعیین شد',
    'picking' => 'در حال دریافت مرسوله',
    'delivered' => 'تحویل داده شد'
);
```

And later in the page, I want to use it inside one of the columns of the dataprovider table as below:

```
[
  'label' => 'Status',
  'format' => 'raw',
  'value' => function ($model, $order_status) {
      return Html::a("<div class='col-sm-8 progress' style='padding: 0px; height: 10px;'>
        <div class='progress-bar ".$model->status."'></div>
      </div><label class='col-sm-4'>".$order_status[$model->status]."</label>", null);
  },
  'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
  'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 300px;']
]
```

But I get empty label. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be you need  `use` for pass the content of the array to the anonymous function eg:

```
  'value' => function ($model)  use ($order_status){
    return Html::a("<div class='col-sm-8 progress' style='padding: 0px; height: 10px;'>
      <div class='progress-bar ".$model->status."'></div>
    </div><label class='col-sm-4'>".$order_status[$model->status]."</label>", null);
  },
```

Comment: I just tried it and I get the error: `Getting unknown property: admin\models\Order::nocourier` Ofcourse my Order model does not have `nocourier` as it is from an external array

Comment: In you code  you don't access to the $model->nocourier .. but to $order_status[$model->status]  then your error seems not related  to the code provide .. c

Comment: I am getting the `$model->status` as the class in the parent div and it works.

Comment: Sorry, As you see in my question, I am using this `$order_status` array to show a custom title for the order status in a label. the label is inside a div with the `progress-bar` class. The div gets the `$model->status` and gets css accordingly, but the inner label does not recognize the `$model->status` as the index of  `$order_status`

Comment: then you should have an index error not a  model error ..  .. please confirm . and check for the real content of $model->status in your function

Comment: `$model->status` does have the statuses I need: `nocourier, delivered, finished, etc.` but `$order_status` seems like not to be what I have defined above. echoing `$order_status[0]` says: `Getting unknown property: admin\models\Order::0`. and the result of var_dump($order_status) is a huge object of Order model

Comment: This mean tha $order_status is not the array you have show in your question  ??  .. check if you reassign this array is some way ..  and second looking to your code you have not $order_status[0] but $order_status[ 'nocourier'], ..

Answer (score 0):

i dont know this language but i can se one things that is wrong.
you are creating a function that containe $order_status. so when you call Value you have to pass on $order_status

```
Value($model , $order_status) for it to work.
```

i would call $order_status parameter for somthing else too.

Comment: Thanks Alen but That was the first thing i tried as you can see in the question!